# Swap using Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

In the code below in order to swap between `px` and `py` you need a pointer to point to the address of `py` and `px` to swap them effectively.

My question is with the `int temp` when the value of `px` is put into it how does it give the correct value back because there is no pointer pointing to it to be able to give the right value and how is the address of `int temp` not clone to give a wrong value?

```
void swap(int px, int py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = px;
    px = py;
    py = temp;
}

//pointer version

void swap(int *px, int *py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
```

Comment: *when the value of px* <= It's not the value of `px`, it's the value of the `int` `px` points to.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. You cannot just pass values and expect they change the originals. Provide a [mcve] and see [ask]!

Comment: If you are asking how the second version could work being temp an int, and not a pointer like the two parameters, it's because it swaps the values pointed to by them, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: @Olaf the first function give wrong answers because there is pointer pointing to an address so the results are not what is expected but in the second version there is also no pointer pointing to the (int temp) so why is giving the expected value and not changing the value that was put into it?

Comment: @Themind - do you consider your question answered by one of the two answers? If so, please accept the relevant answer.

Comment: @4386427 no please i understand all they are saying but my question is but why that?

Comment: @Themind: The first version does not even have a pointer, so what are you talking about? No offence, but your last comment is also unclear. I'd strongly recommend to read a good C book; I have the impression that quite some of the basics about functions and pointers are either missing or there is a massive missconception. Anyway, when reading the chapters **in order** this should become clear.

Comment: @Themind - I tried to explain it using some other words.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions swap the `int` values.  But does that swap affect the calling code's `int`s?

With the second `swap()`, the effect of the swap is seen in the original `a,b` as that function works with the addresses of the *original* `a,b`.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
swap_version2(&a, &b);
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);  // prints 2 1
```

With the first `swap()`, the effect of the swapped is *not* seen in the original `c,d`. as the `swap()` function was swapping copies of `c,d`.  Net effect: the first swap function simply wastes time.  It does not swap `c,d`.

```
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
swap_version1(c, d);
printf("%d %d\n", c, d);  // prints 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two important things you need to know.

1) When calling a function in C, the arguments are always passed by value. If you make changes **inside the functions** to the variables holding the passed value, the changes will be lost the moment the function returns. In other words - any change made inside the function can't be seen outside the function.

2) When working with pointer the `*` operator in front of the pointer means `the location pointed to by the pointer`. It is called dereferencing the pointer. So if you do `*px = 5;` you do **not** change any pointer value! You change the value at the location pointed to by the pointer.

A closer look at your code:

In your first example you have something like:

```
void swap(int px, int py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = px;
    px = py;
    py = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 100;
    swap(x, y);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
 }
```

In C everything is passed by value. So when you call `swap` it is the values `10` and `100` which is passed to the function. It is **not** the variables `x` and `y`. In other words - `px` and `py` in the function has nothing to do with the variable `x` and `y` in `main`. This means that any change made to the variables `px` and `py` is lost when the function returns and `x` and `y` does **not** change.

Your second example is like this:

```
void swap(int px, int py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 100;
    swap(&x, &y);  // Notice the & operator
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
 }
```

As always we have pass by value. But in this case the values that you pass is the values of two `pointer to int`. More specific you pass the address of `x` and `y`.

Like before you can't change the **value** that is passed to the function (just like the first example) but you **can** change the value of whatever the pointer is pointing to.

Here you need to know that `*` in front of the pointer access whatever the pointer is pointing to.

So doing `temp = *px` will read the value pointed to by `px`. In this case it is `10` so `temp` gets the value `10`.

Doing `*px = *py` reads the value `py` points to (i.e. 100) and place it where `px` points (i.e. `x` in `main` is now `100`).

Doing `*py = temp` reads the value `temp` holds (i.e. 10) and place it where `py` points (i.e. `y` in `main` is now `10`).

So when the function returns, the value of `x` and `y` has been swapped.

Notice that the code never uses a pointer to (aka the address of) `temp`. The variable `temp` is just used as an ordinary `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
void swap(int *px, int *py)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *px;
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
```

there are swapped values pointed to by `px` and `py`. The function does not swap the pointers themselves.

To swap the values pointed to by the pointers you need an intermediate memory where temporary to store the value pointed to by `px` that will be overwritten by the value pointed to by `py`.

Thus the function uses local variable `temp` that temporary stores the value `*px`.

Pay attention to that in this assignment statement

```
temp = *px;
```

the variable `temp` stores the value pointed to by `px` that is `*px` that has type `int`. It is not the pointer `px` itself that is assigned to `temp`.